# Быстрое генерирование модуля в nest.js

Tags: nestjs, nest.js

Можно ли как то быстро сгенирировать структуру в nest.js, чтобы не набирать друг за другом команды:

```
- nest generate module roles
- nest generate service roles
- nest generate controller roles
```

Было бы классно использовать что-то типа `nest generate module,service,controller roles`.

Может кто-нибудь знает решение?

Comment: nest g resource --no-spec

Answer (score -1, accepted):

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

```
nest g resource
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не нужно вбивать повторяющиеся символы. Ограничение на минимальное количество символов в ответе стоит для того, чтобы участники писали хотя минимальное объяснение.